# Bash menu for accessing network equipment

Tags: bash, console, ssh

I wrote [a menu in bash](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33222611/menu.txt) to access network equipment, but now there are too many of them to show in one screen to permit selecting one without scrolling up or down. I need it to be improved.

I've considered having two files:

The list of each equipment. Inside this file are the headers and an ID to determine if equipment uses SSH or Telnet.

Allowing entering into two modes: one where each equipment of lists would be printed with a number to allow selecting of any. The other mode allows entering a search mode.

```
#
#
green='\e[0;32m' # '\e[1;32m' is too bright for white bg.
bred='\e[1;31m' # Red
endColor='\e[0m'
ylw='\e[0;33m' # Yellow

clear

# Display welcome message
echo -e "${ylw}
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                        W   A   R   N   I   N   G
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
${endColor}"
#
read -p "Press [Enter] to continue ..."
clear
while :
do
clear
LISTA="${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[1] ESP_R7609_MTSO${endColor}\n
${green}[2] ESP_R7609_RIGUERO${endColor}\n
${green}[3] ESP_R7609_SUBASTA${endColor}\n
${green}[4] ESP_R7606_BOLONIA${endColor}\n
${green}[5] ESP_R7609_LINDAVISTA${endColor}\n
${green}[6] ESP_R7609_UCA${endColor}\n
${green}[7] ESP_R7606S_01D${endColor}\n
${green}[8] ESP_R7606S_02D${endColor}\n
${green}[9] ESP_R7606_MTSO_01${endColor}\n
${green}[10] ESP_R7606_MTSO_02${endColor}\n
${green}[11] ESP_R7206_01D${endColor}\n
${green}[12] ESP_R7206_02D${endColor}\n
${green}[13] ESP_R4507_01D${endColor}\n
${green}[14] ESP_R4503_01D${endColor}\n
${green}[15] ESP_R7609S_GRANADA_01${endColor}\n
${green}[16] ESP_R7609S_GRANADA_02${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[30] ESP_MWR2941_BAC${endColor}\n        
${green}[31] ESP_MWR2941_UCA${endColor}\n       
${green}[32] ESP_MWR2941_UCA2${endColor}\n       
${green}[33] ESP_MWR2941_3F${endColor}\n         
${green}[34] ESP_MWR2941_3F2${endColor}\n       
${green}[35] ESP_MWR2941_ERICSSON${endColor}\n             
${green}[36] ESP_MWR2941_CIUDADJARDIN${endColor}\n  
${green}[37] ESP_MWR2941_CATARINA_01${endColor}\n   
${green}[39] ESP_MWR2941_BOLONIA${endColor}\n               
${green}[40] ESP_MWR2941_BOLONIA2${endColor}\n             
${green}[41] ESP_MWR2941_SANJUDAS${endColor}\n            
${green}[42] ESP_MWR2941_UNICA${endColor}\n
${green}[43] ESP_MWR2941_LOMAS_SAN_JUDAS${endColor}\n       
${green}[44] ESP_MWR2941_MASAYA_CENTRO${endColor}\n
${green}[45] ESP_MWR2941_ONDAS_DE_LUZ${endColor}\n
${green}[46] ESP_MWR2941_SANTANA${endColor}\n
${green}[47] ESP_MWR2941_27MAYO${endColor}\n
${green}[48] ESP_MWR2941_MORAZAN${endColor}\n
${green}[49] ESP_MWR2941_MONTEFRESCO_01${endColor}\n
${green}[50] ESP_MWR2941_PENASBLANCAS${endColor}\n
${green}[51] ESP_MWR2941_EAAI${endColor}\n
${green}[52] ESP_MWR2941_VILLAFONTANA${endColor}\n
${green}[53] ESP_MWR2941_LASCOLINAS${endColor}\n
${green}[54] ESP_MWR2941_SISTEMATICA${endColor}\n
${green}[55] ESP_MWR2941_LARREYNAGA${endColor}\n
${green}[56] ESP_MWR2941_SUBASTA${endColor}\n
${green}[57] ESP_MWR2941_PLAZA_ESPANA${endColor}\n
${green}[58] ESP_MWR2941_BANPRO${endColor}\n
${green}[59] ESP_MWR2941_EL_HORNO${endColor}\n
${green}[60] ESP_MWR2941_MTSO_01${endColor}\n
${green}[62] ESP_MWR2941_BUENAVISTA${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[70] ESP_ME3800X_CIUDAD_JARDIN${endColor}\n         
${green}[71] ESP_ME3800X_PLAZA_ESPANA${endColor}\n          
${green}[72] ESP_ME3800X_MONTEFRESCO${endColor}\n           
${green}[74] ESP_ME3750_RIVAS${endColor}\n                 
${green}[75] ESP_ME3750_LEON${endColor}\n                   
${green}[76] ESP_ME3750_CHINANDEGA${endColor}\n             
${green}[77] ESP_ME3800X_ROBLES${endColor}\n                         
${green}[78] ESP_ME3800X_LARREYNAGA${endColor}\n                                
${green}[79] ESP_ME3800X_VILLAFLOR${endColor}\n                                 
${green}[80] ESP_ME3800X_PACAYA${endColor}\n                                    
${green}[81] ESP_ME3800X_3F${endColor}\n                                        
${green}[82] ESP_ME3750_HATO_GRANDE${endColor}\n                                
${green}[83] ESP_ME3750_LAGUNA${endColor}\n                                     
${green}[84] ESP_ME3750_LA_GATEADA${endColor}\n                                 
${green}[85] ESP_ME3750_QUISUCA${endColor}\n                        
${green}[86] ESP_ME3800X_SANMARCOS${endColor}\n
${green}[87] ESP_ME3800X_JINOTEPE${endColor}\n
${green}[88] ESP_ME3750_GRANADA${endColor}\n
${green}[89] ESP_ME3800X_GRTXN${endColor}\n
${green}[90] ESP_ME3600X_RIVAS${endColor}\n
${green}[91] ESP_ME3600X_ESTELI${endColor}\n
${green}[92] ESP_ME3600X_LACUESTA${endColor}\n
${green}[93] ESP_ME3600X_CHICOSLAPA${endColor}\n
${green}[94] ESP_ME3600X_JUIGALPA${endColor}\n
${green}[95] ESP_ME3600X_HATOGRANDE${endColor}\n
${green}[96] ESP_ME3800X_LAPAZCENTRO${endColor}\n
${green}[97] ESP_ME3600X_LASBRISAS${endColor}\n
${green}[98] ESP_ME3800X_LEON${endColor}\n
${green}[99] ESP_ME3800X_CHINANDEGA${endColor}\n
${green}[100] ESP_ME3600X_BUENAVISTA${endColor}\n
${green}[101] ESP_ME3600X_ELHORNO${endColor}\n 
${green}[103] ESP_ME3600X_LALIMA${endColor}\n    
${green}[105] ESP_ME3600X_MATAYAGUAL${endColor}\n
${green}[102] ESP_ME3600X_PENASBLANCAS${endColor}\n
${green}[104] ESP_ME3600X_QUISUCA${endColor}\n
${green}[106] ESP_ME3750_VERACRUZ${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[120] ESP_ME6524_TIPITAPA${endColor}\n
${green}[121] ESP_ME6524_UNICA${endColor}\n
${green}[122] ESP_ME6524_MASAYA${endColor}\n
${green}[123] ESP_ME6524_CATARINA${endColor}\n
${green}[124] ESP_ME6524_CERRO_ORO${endColor}\n
${green}[125] ESP_ME6524_CHONCO${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[130] ESP_NX3048_MTSO${endColor}\n
${green}[131] ESP_NX3048_TIPITAPA${endColor}\n
${green}[132] ESP_NX3048_CHINANDEGA${endColor}\n
${green}[133] ESP_NX3048_CATARINA${endColor}\n
${green}[134] ESP_NX3048_UNICA${endColor}\n
${green}[135] ESP_NX3048_LARREYNAGA${endColor}\n
${green}[136] ESP_NX3064_MTSO_01${endColor}\n
${green}[137] ESP_NX3064_MTSO_02${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[150] ESP_ASR901_ACCEDO${endColor}\n
${green}[151] ESP_ASR901_GRANADA_CAP${endColor}\n
${green}[152] ESP_ASR901_GRANADA_CENTRO${endColor}\n
${green}[153] ESP_ASR901_DIRIOMO${endColor}\n
${green}[154] ESP_ASR901_DIRIOMO_CATARINA${endColor}\n
${green}[155] ESP_ASR901_NIQUINOMO_MASATEPE${endColor}\n
${green}[156] ESP_ASR901_MASATEPE${endColor}\n
${green}[157] ESP_ASR901_SAN_MARCOS_JINOTEPE${endColor}\n
${green}[158] ESP_ASR901_JINOTEPE_CENTRO${endColor}\n
${green}[159] ESP_ASR901_DIRIAMBA_CENTRO${endColor}\n
${green}[160] ESP_ASR901_DIRIAMBA${endColor}\n
${green}[161] ESP_ASR901_LAS_ESQUINAS${endColor}\n
${green}[162] ESP_ASR901_K13_CRTRA_SUR${endColor}\n
${green}[163] ESP_ASR901_COBIRSA2${endColor}\n
${green}[164] ESP_ASR901_ANX_DUCUALI${endColor}\n
${green}[165] ESP_ASR901_ALTAMIRA${endColor}\n
${green}[166] ESP_ASR901_JDE${endColor}\n
${green}[167] ESP_ASR901_AJAXDELGADO${endColor}\n
${green}[168] ESP_ASR901_KATIB${endColor}\n
${green}[169] ESP_ASR901_ONDAS_LUZ_2${endColor}\n
${green}[170] ESP_ASR901_TENDERI${endColor}\n
${green}[171] ESP_ASR901_TENDERI_2${endColor}\n
${green}[172] ESP_ASR901_100N${endColor}\n
${green}[173] ESP_ASR901_ENTRADA_ESQUIPULAS${endColor}\n
${green}[174] ESP_ASR901_COSTARICA${endColor}\n
${green}[175] ESP_ASR901_LASMERCEDES${endColor}\n
${green}[176] ESP_ASR901_UNDPROPOSITO2${endColor}\n
${green}[177] ESP_ASR901_ASTROCARTON${endColor}\n
${green}[178] ESP_ASR901_IVANMONTENEGRO${endColor}\n
${green}[179] ESP_ASR901_LAFUENTE${endColor}\n
${green}[180] ESP_ASR901_NICARAO${endColor}\n
${green}[181] ESP_ASR901_ENTRADA_LASFLORES${endColor}\n
${green}[182] ESP_ASR901_SINACOI${endColor}\n
${green}[183] ESP_ASR901_WASPANSUR${endColor}\n
${green}[184] ESP_ASR901_MASAYA6${endColor}\n
${green}[185] ESP_ASR901_ENACAL${endColor}\n
${green}[186] ESP_ASR901_NUEVODIARIO${endColor}\n
${green}[187] ESP_ASR901_HOLIDAYINN${endColor}\n
${green}[188] ESP_ASR901_ZONAFRANCA${endColor}\n
${green}[189] ESP_ASR901_ANX_VILLAVENEZUELA${endColor}\n
${green}[190] ESP_ASR901_GUANACASTILLO${endColor}\n
${green}[191] ESP_ASR901_SOMOTILLO${endColor}\n
${green}[192] ESP_ASR901_K160${endColor}\n
${green}[193] ESP_ASR901_MINA_LIMON${endColor}\n
${green}[194] ESP_ASR901_SANJUDASPISTA${endColor}\n
${green}[195] ESP_ASR901_SEMEMORIALSANDINO${endColor}\n
${green}[196] ESP_ASR901_VILLAFONTANA_2${endColor}\n
${green}[197] ESP_ASR901_MTSO_01${endColor}\n
${green}[198] ESP_ASR901_CHILTEPE${endColor}\n
${green}[199] ESP_ASR901_K35MSYGRA${endColor}\n
${green}[200] ESP_ASR901_SEBACO${endColor}\n
${green}[201] ESP_ASR901_ROBERRTOHUEMBES${endColor}\n
${green}[202] ESP_ASR901_METROCENTRO2${endColor}\n
${green}[203] ESP_ASR901_WASPAN2PEPSI${endColor}\n
${green}[204] ESP_ASR901_JUZGADOS${endColor}\n
${green}[205] ESP_ASR901_TIENDAEJERCITO${endColor}\n
${green}[206] ESP_ASR901_BATCA${endColor}\n
${green}[207] ESP_ASR901_ABERDEEN${endColor}\n
${green}[208] ESP_ASR901_SAN_RAMON${endColor}\n
${green}[209] ESP_ASR901_OCHOMOGO${endColor}\n
${green}[210] ESP_ASR901_K44MSYGRA${endColor}\n
${green}[211] ESP_ASR901_AGRICORP${endColor}\n
${green}[212] ESP_ASR901_LOSPERROS${endColor}\n
${green}[213] ESP_ASR901_LEON_DISNORTE${endColor}\n
${green}[214] ESP_ASR901_CANAL2${endColor}\n
${green}[215] ESP_ASR901_EDIFICIO_DELTA${endColor}\n
${green}[216] ESP_ASR901_RIVASPARQUECENTRAL${endColor}\n
${green}[217] ESP_ASR901_CASATERAN${endColor}\n
${green}[218] ESP_ASR901_CASAPUEBLOS${endColor}\n
${green}[219] ESP_ASR901_VERACRUZ${endColor}\n
${green}[220] ESP_ASR901_ALTAGRACIA${endColor}\n
${green}[221] ESP_ASR901_ELTUMA${endColor}\n
${green}[222] ESP_ASR901_NANDAIME${endColor}\n
${green}[223] ESP_ASR901_IBW${endColor}\n
${green}[224] ESP_ASR901_INCAE2${endColor}\n
${green}[225] ESP_ASR901_TICOMO${endColor}\n
${green}[226] ESP_ASR901_ENTRADA_TICUANTEPE${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[250] ESP_SWES228_VERACRUZ${endColor}\n
${green}[251] ESP_SWES228_VILLA_FONTANA${endColor}\n
${green}[253] ESP_SWSF302_UCA2${endColor}\n
${green}[254] ESP_SWSF302_ROT_GUEGUENSE${endColor}\n
${green}[255] ESP_SWSF320_PLAYA_ROSADA${endColor}\n
${green}[256] ESP_SWES228_CHIQUILISTAGUA${endColor}\n
${green}[257] ESP_SWES228_MASAYA_CENTRO${endColor}\n
${green}[258] ESP_SWSF302_PTO${endColor}\n
${green}[259] ESP_SWSF302_SANJUDAS${endColor}\n
${green}[260] ESP_SWSF302_SANJUDAS3${endColor}\n
${green}[261] ESP_SWSF302_CRTRA_TICUANTEPE${endColor}\n
${green}[262] ESP_SWSF302_GRANADA_01${endColor}\n
${green}[263] ESP_SWSF302_VERACRUZ3${endColor}\n
${green}[264] ESP_SWES228_ROBERTO_TERAN${endColor}\n
${green}[265] ESP_SWES228_DISCOVERY${endColor}\n
${green}[266] ESP_SWSF302_CIUDAD_DARIO${endColor}\n
${green}[267] ESP_SWSF302_SAPOA${endColor}\n
${green}[268] ESP_SWSF302_ACOYAPA${endColor}\n
${green}[269] ESP_SWSF302_MALPAISILLO${endColor}\n
${green}[270] ESP_SWSF302_SIUNA${endColor}\n
${green}[271] ESP_SWSF302_LOSLLANOS${endColor}\n
${green}[272] ESP_SWSF302_PLAYA_EL_COCO${endColor}\n
${green}[273] ESP_SWSF302_PUERTOSANDINO${endColor}\n
${green}[274] ESP_SWSF302_SANIGNACIOCONCEPCION${endColor}\n
${green}[275] ESP_SWSF302_CUAPA${endColor}\n
${green}[276] ESP_SWSF302_CARDENAS${endColor}\n
${green}[277] ESP_SWSF302_RANCHOGRANDE${endColor}\n
${green}[278] ESP_SWSF302_WIWILINUEVASEGOVIA${endColor}\n
${green}[279] ESP_SWSF302_SALINASGRANDES${endColor}\n
${green}[280] ESP_SWSF302_BOACOVIEJO${endColor}\n
${green}[281] ESP_SWSF302_ESTPOLGRA${endColor}\n
${green}[282] ESP_SWSF302_RAJUENSE${endColor}\n
${green}[283] ESP_SWSF302_ELCOMEJEN${endColor}\n
${green}[284] ESP_SWSF302_JIQUILILLO${endColor}\n
${green}[285] ESP_SWSF302_GRANADA_02${endColor}\n
${green}[286] ESP_SWSF302_PUNTATEONOSTE${endColor}\n
${green}[287] ESP_SWSF302_SANJOSECUSMAPA${endColor}\n
${green}[288] ESP_SWSF302_POLARIS${endColor}\n
${green}[289] ESP_SWSF302_LASTORRES${endColor}\n
${green}[290] ESP_SWSF302_CERROLARGO${endColor}\n
${green}[291] ESP_SWSF302_ALMENDRO${endColor}\n
${green}[292] ESP_SWF302_TICUANTEPE${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[300] ESP_SWIE3010_EL_VIEJO${endColor}\n
${green}[301] ESP_SWIE3010_TIPITAPA4${endColor}\n
${green}[302] ESP_SWIE3010_LOS_VALCANES${endColor}\n
${green}[303] ESP_SWIE3010_ABERDEEN${endColor}\n
${green}[304] ESP_SWIE3010_SBENITO${endColor}\n
${green}[305] ESP_SWIE3010_MBONILLA${endColor}\n
${green}[306] ESP_SWIE3010_TIPITAPA8${endColor}\n
${green}[308] ESP_SWIE3010_MATAGALPA${endColor}\n
${green}[309] ESP_SWIE3010_PACAYA${endColor}\n
${green}[310] ESP_SWIE3010_JINOTEPE${endColor}\n
${green}[311] ESP_SWIE3010_LALIMA${endColor}\n
${green}[312] ESP_SWIE3010_ELTUMA${endColor}\n
${green}[313] ESP_SWIE3010_VILLAFLOR${endColor}\n
${green}[314] ESP_SWIE3010_MASAYA_CENTRO${endColor}\n
${green}[315] ESP_SWIE3010_MONTEFRESCO${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[400] ESP_FWSM_01${endColor}\n
${green}[401] ESP_FWSM_02${endColor}\n
${green}[402] ESP_CAT3550_COFRADIA${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
${green}[500] ESP_MX960_MTSO${endColor}\n
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}\n
Enter your menu choice [0 exit]:"
echo -e $LISTA
echo "   Pattern to search:"
read PATRON
echo -e $LISTA | grep -i $PATRON
read yourchoice
case $yourchoice in
1) ssh ESP_R7609S_MTSO;;
2) ssh ESP_R7609_RIGUERO;;
3) telnet ESP_R7609_SUBASTA;;
4) ssh ESP_R7606_BOLONIA;;
5) ssh ESP_R7609_LINDAVISTA;;
6) ssh ESP_R7609_UCA;;
7) ssh ESP_R7606S_01D;;
8) ssh ESP_R7606S_02D;;
9) ssh ESP_R7606_MTSO_01;;
10) ssh ESP_R7606_MTSO_02;;
11) telnet ESP_R7206_01D;;
12) telnet ESP_R7206_02D;;
13) telnet ESP_R4507_01D;;
14) telnet ESP_R4503_01D;;
15) ssh ESP_R7609S_GRANADA_01;;
16) ssh ESP_R7609S_GRANADA_02;;
# MWR2941
30) ssh ESP_MWR2941_BAC;;
31) ssh ESP_MWR2941_UCA;;
32) telnet ESP_MWR2941_UCA2;;
33) telnet ESP_MWR2941_3F;;
34) telnet ESP_MWR2941_3F2;;
35) telnet ESP_MWR2941_ERICSSON;;
36) telnet ESP_MWR2941_CIUDADJARDIN;;
37) telnet ESP_MWR2941_CATARINA_01;;
39) ssh ESP_MWR2941_BOLONIA;;
40) telnet ESP_MWR2941_BOLONIA2;;
41) telnet ESP_MWR2941_SANJUDAS;;
42) telnet ESP_MWR2941_UNICA;;
43) telnet ESP_MWR2941_LOMAS_SAN_JUDAS;;
44) telnet ESP_MWR2941_MASAYA_CENTRO;;
45) telnet ESP_MWR2941_ONDAS_DE_LUZ;;
46) telnet ESP_MWR2941_SANTANA;;
47) telnet ESP_MWR2941_27MAYO;;
48) telnet ESP_MWR2941_MORAZAN;;
49) telnet ESP_MWR2941_MONTEFRESCO_01;;
50) ssh ESP_MWR2941_PENASBLANCAS;;
51) telnet ESP_MWR2941_EAAI;;
52) telnet ESP_MWR2941_VILLAFONTANA;;
53) ssh ESP_MWR2941_LASCOLINAS;;
54) telnet ESP_MWR2941_SISTEMATICA;;
55) telnet ESP_MWR2941_LARREYNAGA;;
56) telnet ESP_MWR2941_SUBASTA;;
57) telnet ESP_MWR2941_PLAZA_ESPANA;;
58) telnet ESP_MWR2941_BANPRO;;
59) telnet ESP_MWR2941_EL_HORNO;;
60) telnet ESP_MWR2941_MTSO_01;;
62) telnet ESP_MWR2941_BUENAVISTA;;
# SW ME 3600 / 3750 / 3800
70) ssh ESP_ME3800X_CIUDAD_JARDIN;;
71) ssh ESP_ME3800X_PLAZA_ESPANA;;
72) ssh ESP_ME3800X_MONTEFRESCO;;
74) ssh ESP_ME3750_RIVAS;;
75) ssh ESP_ME3750_LEON;;
76) ssh ESP_ME3750_CHINANDEGA;;
77) ssh ESP_ME3800X_ROBLES;;
78) ssh ESP_ME3800X_LARREYNAGA;;
79) ssh ESP_ME3800X_VILLAFLOR;;
80) ssh ESP_ME3800X_PACAYA;;
81) ssh ESP_ME3800X_3F;;
82) ssh ESP_ME3750_HATO_GRANDE;;
83) ssh ESP_ME3750_LAGUNA;;
84) ssh ESP_ME3750_LA_GATEADA;;
85) ssh ESP_ME3750_QUISUCA;;
86) ssh ESP_ME3800X_SANMARCOS;;
87) ssh ESP_ME3800X_JINOTEPE;;
88) ssh ESP_ME3750_GRANADA;;
89) ssh ESP_ME3800X_GRTXN;;
90) ssh ESP_ME3600X_RIVAS;;
91) ssh ESP_ME3600X_ESTELI;;
92) ssh ESP_ME3600X_LACUESTA;;
93) ssh ESP_ME3600X_CHICOSLAPA;;
94) ssh ESP_ME3600X_JUIGALPA;;
95) ssh ESP_ME3600X_HATOGRANDE;;
96) ssh ESP_ME3800X_LAPAZCENTRO;;
97) ssh ESP_ME3600X_LASBRISAS;;
98) ssh ESP_ME3800X_LEON;;
99) ssh ESP_ME3800X_CHINANDEGA;;
100) ssh ESP_ME3600X_BUENAVISTA;;
101) ssh ESP_ME3600X_ELHORNO;;
102) ssh ESP_ME3600X_PENASBLANCAS;;
103) telnet ESP_ME3600X_LALIMA;;
104) ssh ESP_ME3600X_QUISUCA;;
105) ssh ESP_ME3800X_MATAYAGUAL;;
106) ssh ESP_ME3750_VERACRUZ;;
# SW ME 6500
120) ssh ESP_ME6524_TIPITAPA;;
121) ssh ESP_ME6524_UNICA;;
122) ssh ESP_ME6524_MASAYA;;
123) ssh ESP_ME6524_CATARINA;;
124) ssh ESP_ME6524_CERRO_ORO;;
125) ssh ESP_ME6524_CHONCO;;
# NEXUS
130) ssh ESP_NX3048_MTSO;;
131) ssh ESP_NX3048_TIPITAPA;;
132) ssh ESP_NX3048_CHINANDEGA;;
133) ssh ESP_NX3048_CATARINA;;
134) ssh ESP_NX3048_UNICA;;
135) ssh ESP_NX3048_LARREYNAGA;;
136) ssh ESP_NX3064_MTSO_01;;
137) ssh ESP_NX3064_MTSO_02;;
# ASR901
150) ssh ESP_ASR901_ACCEDO;;
151) ssh ESP_ASR901_GRANADA_CAP;;
152) ssh ESP_ASR901_GRANADA_CENTRO;;
153) ssh ESP_ASR901_DIRIOMO;;
154) ssh ESP_ASR901_DIRIOMO_CATARINA;;
155) ssh ESP_ASR901_NIQUINOMO_MASATEPE;;
156) ssh ESP_ASR901_MASATEPE;;
157) ssh ESP_ASR901_SAN_MARCOS_JINOTEPE;;
158) ssh ESP_ASR901_JINOTEPE_CENTRO;;
159) ssh ESP_ASR901_DIRIAMBA_CENTRO;;
160) ssh ESP_ASR901_DIRIAMBA;;
161) ssh ESP_ASR901_LAS_ESQUINAS;;
162) ssh ESP_ASR901_K13_CRTRA_SUR;;
163) ssh ESP_ASR901_COBIRSA2;;
164) ssh ESP_ASR901_ANX_DUCUALI;;
165) ssh ESP_ASR901_ALTAMIRA;;
166) ssh ESP_ASR901_JDE;;
167) ssh ESP_ASR901_AJAXDELGADO;;
168) ssh ESP_ASR901_KATIB;;
169) ssh ESP_ASR901_ONDAS_LUZ_2;;
170) ssh ESP_ASR901_TENDERI;;
171) ssh ESP_ASR901_TENDERI_2;;
172) ssh ESP_ASR901_100N;;
173) ssh ESP_ASR901_ENTRADA_ESQUIPULAS;;
174) ssh ESP_ASR901_COSTARICA;;
175) ssh ESP_ASR901_LASMERCEDES;;
176) ssh ESP_ASR901_UNDPROPOSITO2;;
177) ssh ESP_ASR901_ASTROCARTON;;
178) ssh ESP_ASR901_IVANMONTENEGRO;;
179) ssh ESP_ASR901_LAFUENTE;;
180) ssh ESP_ASR901_NICARAO;;
181) ssh ESP_ASR901_ENTRADA_LASFLORES;;
182) ssh ESP_ASR901_SINACOI;;
183) ssh ESP_ASR901_WASPANSUR;;
184) ssh ESP_ASR901_MASAYA6;;
185) ssh ESP_ASR901_ENACAL;;
186) ssh ESP_ASR901_NUEVODIARIO;;
187) ssh ESP_ASR901_HOLIDAYINN;;
188) ssh ESP_ASR901_ZONAFRANCA;;
189) ssh ESP_ASR901_ANX_VILLAVENEZUELA;;
190) ssh ESP_ASR901_GUANACASTILLO;;
191) ssh ESP_ASR901_SOMOTILLO;;
192) ssh ESP_ASR901_K160;;
193) ssh ESP_ASR901_MINA_LIMON;;
194) ssh ESP_ASR901_SANJUDASPISTA;;
195) ssh ESP_ASR901_SEMEMORIALSANDINO;;
196) ssh ESP_ASR901_VILLAFONTANA2;;
197) ssh ESP_ASR901_MTSO_01;;
198) ssh ESP_ASR901_CHILTEPE;;
199) ssh ESP_ASR901_K35MSYGRA;;
200) ssh ESP_ASR901_SEBACO;;
201) ssh ESP_ASR901_ROBERTOHUEMBES;;
202) ssh ESP_ASR901_METROCENTRO2;;
203) ssh ESP_ASR901_WASPAN2PEPSI;;
204) ssh ESP_ASR901_JUZGADOS;;
205) ssh ESP_ASR901_TIENDAEJERCITO;;
206) ssh ESP_ASR901_BATCA;;
207) ssh ESP_ASR901_ABERDEEN;;
208) ssh ESP_ASR901_SAN_RAMON;;
209) ssh ESP_ASR901_OCHOMOGO;;
210) ssh ESP_ASR901_K44MSYGRA;;
211) ssh ESP_ASR901_AGRICORP;;
212) ssh ESP_ASR901_LOSPERROS;;
213) ssh ESP_ASR901_LEON_DISNORTE;;
214) ssh ESP_ASR901_CANAL2;;
215) ssh ESP_ASR901_EDIFICIO_DELTA;;
216) ssh ESP_ASR901_RIVASPARQUECENTRAL;;
217) ssh ESP_ASR901_CASATERAN;;
218) ssh ESP_ASR901_CASAPUEBLOS;;
219) ssh ESP_ASR901_VERACRUZ;;
220) ssh ESP_ASR901_ALTAGRACIA;;
221) ssh ESP_ASR901_ELTUMA;;
222) telnet ESP_ASR901_NANDAIME;;
223) ssh ESP_ASR901_IBW;;
224) ssh ESP_ASR901_INCAE2;;
225) ssh ESP_ASR901_TICOMO;;
226) ssh ESP_ASR901_ENTRADA_TICUANTEPE;;
# SW 228
250) telnet ESP_SWEL228_VERACRUZ;;
251) telnet ESP_SWEL228_VILLA_FONTANA;;
253) ssh ESP_SWSF302_UCA2;;
254) ssh ESP_SWSF302_ROT_GUEGUENSE;;
255) ssh ESP_SWSF320_PLAYA_ROSADA;;
256) telnet ESP_SWES228_CHIQUILISTAGUA;;
257) telnet ESP_SWES228_MASAYA_CENTRO;;
258) ssh ESP_SWSF302_RPTO;;
259) ssh ESP_SWSF300_SANJUDAS;;
260) ssh ESP_SWSF302_SANJUDAS3;;
261) ssh ESP_SWSF302_CRTRA_TICUANTEPE;;
262) ssh ESP_SWSF302_GRANADA_01;;
263) ssh ESP_SWSF302_VERACRUZ3;;
264) telnet ESP_SWES228_ROBERTO_TERAN;;
265) telnet ESP_EL228_DISCOVERY;;
266) ssh ESP_SWSF302_CIUDAD_DARIO;;
267) ssh ESP_SWSF302_SAPOA;;
268) ssh ESP_SWSF302_ACOYAPA;;
269) ssh ESP_SWSF302_MALPAISILLO;;
270) ssh ESP_SWSF302_SIUNA;;
271) ssh ESP_SWSF302_LOSLLANOS;;
272) ssh ESP_SWSF302_PLAYA_EL_COCO;;
273) ssh ESP_SWSF302_PUERTOSANDINO;;
274) ssh ESP_SWSF302_SANIGNACIOCONCEPCION;;
275) ssh ESP_SWSF302_CUAPA;;
276) ssh ESP_SWSF302_CARDENAS;;
277) ssh ESP_SWSF302_RANCHOGRANDE;;
278) ssh ESP_SWSF302_WIWILINUEVASEGOVIA;;
279) ssh ESP_SWSF302_SALINASGRANDES;;
280) ssh ESP_SWSF302_BOACOVIEJO;;
281) ssh ESP_SWSF302_ESTPOLGRA;;
282) ssh ESP_SWSF302_RAJUENSE;;
283) ssh ESP_SWSF302_ELCOMEJEN;;
284) ssh ESP_SWSF302_JIQUILILLO;;
285) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_GRANADA_02;;
286) ssh ESP_SWSF302_PUNTATEONOSTE;;
287) ssh ESP_SWSF302_SANJOSECUSMAPA;;
288) ssh ESP_SWSF302_POLARIS;;
289) ssh ESP_SWSF302_LASTORRES;;
290) ssh ESP_SWSF302_CERROLARGO ;;
291) ssh ESP_SWSF302_ALMENDRO;;
292) ssh ESP_SWF302_TICUANTEPE;;
# SW IE3010
300) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_EL_VIEJO;;
301) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_TIPITAPA4;;
302) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_LOS_VALCANES;;
303) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_ABERDEEN;;
304) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_SBENITO;;
305) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_MBONILLA;;
306) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_TIPITAPA8;;
308) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_MATAGALPA;;
309) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_PACAYA;;
310) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_JINOTEPE;;
311) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_LALIMA;;
312) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_ELTUMA;;
313) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_VILLAFLOR;;
314) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_MASAYA_CENTRO;;
315) ssh ESP_SWIE3010_MONTEFRESCO;;
#
400) telnet FWSM1;;
401) telnet FWSM2;;
402) ssh ESP_CAT3550_COFRADIA;;
#
500) ssh ESP_MX960_MTSO;;
#
0) exit;;
*) echo "Opps!!! Please select a valid choice ";
echo "Press a key. . ." ; read ;;
esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity to enter all those server names manually,
twice: once for the choice number listing, and one more time for the `ssh` / `telnet` command selection.

A better way would have been to create a file with the list of the command-servername pairs, like this:

> ```
> ssh ESP_R7609S_MTSO
> ssh ESP_R7609_RIGUERO
> telnet ESP_R7609_SUBASTA
> ssh ESP_R7606_BOLONIA
> ssh ESP_R7609_LINDAVISTA
> ssh ESP_R7609_UCA
> ```

Let's call this `info.txt`.

Then, the script could read this file into a Bash array:

```
info=($(cat info.txt))
```

The list of choices can be printed with this loop:

```
print_choices() {
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#info[@]}; i += 2)); do
        j=$((i + 1))
        choice=$((i / 2 + 1))
        printf "$green%s$endColor\n" "$choice: ${info[j]}"
    done
}
```

Note that the choice numbers are different from your original,
because I see that some numbers were (inexplicably) skipped.
In this version the listing is programmatic,
so it's orderly, from 1 to 235.

You could use this function to print the list of choices to the user,
and `grep` on its output to filter, just like in the original script.

When the user makes a choice, you could calculate the correct position in the Bash array by applying the reverse logic that I used above in the `print_choices` function (I leave that as an exercise for you).

#### A note about bad practices

When a simple `echo` is not enough,
you need to use any of its flags,
it's better to use `printf` instead,
as it's more portable.

A better way to put a large string into a variable:

```
read -d '' LISTA << EOF
${bred}+----------------------------------------------------------------+${endColor}
${green}[1] ESP_R7609_MTSO${endColor}
${green}[2] ESP_R7609_RIGUERO${endColor}
${green}[3] ESP_R7609_SUBASTA${endColor}
${green}[4] ESP_R7606_BOLONIA${endColor}
EOF
```

Notice that with this way you don't need to put the `\n` line ending characters.

However, it's often a code smell to have large texts in variables.
It's better to put the large text into a separate file,
as I demonstrated above.